# Multi-site User Sessions

Tags: customization, multisite, login, users

I have a client that wants to create several WordPress sites and utilize a "site switcher" at the top, sort of like ThemeForest.net. I know in WP 3 you can create multiple blogs on the same installation, but what about enabling users who login to one blog to be logged into all of the blogs in the WordPress installation? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@brianmcculloh** As @John P Bloch said, **WordPress Multisite is a perfect fit**. The list of sites is what WordPress now calls *a Network*. Here are some resources that you might find helpful:

- [Creating a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) (WordPress Codex)
- [Installing Multiple Blogs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs) (WordPress Codex)
- [How to enable Multi-Site option in WordPress 3.0](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-enable-multi-site-option-in-wordpress-3-0/) (WPBeginner.com)
- [WordPress 3.0 Walkthrough: Getting Started with Multisite](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2010/06/02/wordpress-3-multisite/) (WebToolsCollection.com)
- [WordPress 3.0: Multisite Domain Mapping Tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/) (ottopress.com)
- [WordPress MU Domain Mapping Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) (wordpress.org/extend/plugins)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely. Think of it this way: wordpress.com is a big Multisite install. You're always logged into wordpress.com, regardless of which blog you're on.

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'Multisite Switcher' plugin. I use it to switch from one site to another within the Admin of a multisite install.

I know SuperAdmin can access this feature, but you may(?) need to set capability permissions via the Role Manager plugin for lesser roles to use this feature.